# Complicated law of iterated expectation

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

[image]

I'm having issues with part c). The law of iterated expectation is that for any two random variables $X$ and $Y$:

$E(X)=E[E(X|Y)]$

Is it the case that for any random variables $X,Y,Z$:

$E(X|Z)=E[E(X|Y)|Z]$ (not $E(X|Z)=E[E((X|Y)|Z)]$) , and if so why is this the case, or does it only hold for some form of independence?

If this is correct I just need a rough outline of how this follows from the law of iterated expectation, not sigma algebras and measure.

Comment: Well it is not just any random variables. The sigma algebra generated by $\Theta$ and $X$ contains the sigma algebra generated by $X$. I don't know if there is a non-measure theoretic way of explaining this but for the equality you wrote to hold it must be true that $Z$ is a function of $Y$. Going back to the question from your book the function in question is simply the projection $\pi(\Theta,X) = X$, which is a measurable function.

Answer (score 3):

The nested form of the Law of Iterated Expectation has $E(X\mid Z)=E[E(X\mid Y,Z)\mid Z]$. Since $Z$ is in the outer condition it must be put in the inner condition. Issues of independence aren't involved. Perhaps this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EauZqeAxcM) might help explain it.

That is how the first equality is done.

Second equality: As stated, the conditional independence of $\tilde{X}$ and $X$ given $\Theta$ means that $E[\tilde{X}\mid\Theta,X] = E[\tilde{X}\mid\Theta]$.

Third equality:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E[E[\tilde{X}\mid\Theta]\mid X] &=& E[P(\tilde{X}=1\mid\Theta)\mid X] \qquad\text{since $\tilde{X}$ is either $0$ or $1$} \\
&=& E[\Theta\mid X] \qquad\text{since $X \sim$ Bernoulli with parameter $\Theta$.} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: In the clip although he doesn't state it explicitly, i'm sure that the conclusion is that $E(IQ|F)=E[E(IQ|S,F)|F]$. However $E(IQ|S,F)|F$ is a function of $F$, so when finding its expectation you sum over $F$, whereas in the clip he sums over $S$?

Comment: No, $E(IQ|F)$ is a function of $F$ and so is $E(E(IQ|S,F)|F)$ (since they're equal). It's right to sum over $S$ rather than $F$. In the clip, he evaluates that function of $F$ only for value $F=female$ but he could also evaluate it for the other value $F=male$. Note that $E(IQ|S,F)$ is a function of $S$ and $F$. Taking expecation of that function given $F$ means summing over $S$. You can't sum over $F$ because it is "given", so treated like a constant in a sense.

Comment: @usainlightning Also, summing over $F$ (and $S$) would happen for $E[E(E(IQ|S,F)|F)]$ which results in just a number equal to $E(IQ)$.

Comment: I get that $E(IQ|S,F)$ is a function of $F$ and $S$ as for different values of $F$ and $S$ I get a different expectation. However, I'm not sure why $E(IQ|S,F)|F$  is just  a function of $S$. It's rather confusing because it seems that inside the expectation you can allow for different values of $F$ and $S$, but when the "given" is outside the expectation you cannot.

Comment: @MickA Thanks for your answer and for sharing that link, it was great. When I first saw $E[X \mid Z] = E[E[X \mid Y,Z] \mid Z]$ I was like what is this heresy but I should have realized it's like $P(E|F) = P(E|GF)P(G|F) + P(E|G^cF)P(G^c|F)$ which was an earlier concept introduced in my book that made sense to me